# HTTP request works in Postman but not in Ruby (502 error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new to Ruby but have to debug a Ruby code that I did not write.

In the Ruby code, an HTTP request is made. After a bit of logging, I found out that the response object shows a 502 error. When I try the exact same request in Postman, I get the expected successful response :

[image]

I even tried to literally copy/past Postman's generated Ruby snippet, and it still gives me a 502 error when fired from the Ruby code.

Here is the part responsible for the query (the request method, post part) :

```rb
class PatentApi
  # Patent analysis API wrapper

  require 'uri'
  require 'net/http'

  DEFAULT_ENDPOINT = configatron.patent_api.endpoint.freeze

  # POST /api/v1/graph
  def post_complete_patent_graph(data)
    response = post('graph', data.to_json)
    response
  end

  # Send as POST request
  def post(path, options = {})
    request(:post, path, options)
  end

  # Build the request and return response
  def request(method, path, options)
    url = URI.parse(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT + path)
    Rails.logger.info (url.inspect) # The url looks ok in the logs !
    params = options # After logging, this value is ok
    case method
      when :get
        url.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)
        request["Accept"] = 'application/json'
        request["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
        response = http.request(request)
        return response
      when :post
        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
        request.body = params
        response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :read_timeout => 320) do |http|
          http.request(request)
        end
        Rails.logger.info 'RESPONSE'
        Rails.logger.info (response.code) # 502 ! :(
        Rails.logger.info (response.message)
        Rails.logger.info 'END RESPONSE'
        return response
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy in your postman configuration? If so, you'll need to make sure that the same proxy is used for your ruby application.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to include the `Content-Type` header like

```rb
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```